# restricting input after two decimal point with inputformatter in textfield only hide the values after the two decimal numbers

Tags: flutter, dart, decimal, textfield, textinput

I have a TextField that only allows digits with two decimal numbers.

```
                       TextField(
                                  controller: extraAmountController,
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                      RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\,?\d{0,2}'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  keyboardType:
                                      TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                          decimal: true, signed: true),
                                  onChanged: (amount) {
                                    extraAmount = double.parse(amount)
                                        .toStringAsFixed(2);
                                    print(amount.length);
                                    print(extraAmount);
                                  },
                                  onSubmitted: (amount) {
                                    amount.length == 0
                                        ? extraAmountController.text =
                                            extraAmount = "00.00"
                                        : extraAmount = double.parse(amount)
                                            .toStringAsFixed(2);
                                    print(amount.length);
                                    print(extraAmount);
                                  },
                                  textAlignVertical:
                                      TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  cursorColor: Colors.black45,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: usersList.first.extraAmount,
                                    contentPadding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    suffixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.business_center,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Now the problem is the text we gave after the two decimal points.
After we give the decimal values, We can still able to type. But, it won't make any changes in the text field. But, if we press the backspace, it will delete the value, Typed after the two decimal points. Then only we can be able to edit the actual value in the text field. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `enabled` parameter and set it to true if you dont want to make it editable anymore.

```
new TextField(
    enabled: false, 
    ...
    ...
)
```